# Sql iphone error no such table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I have a problem with sql lite in my app. I cause an error "No such table" when try to insert data in table. I create database file on documents directory and after i create a table (this table creates without errors in my program but doesnt create in database).  Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly check the database path, then go to database path. Check it.
2. Delete the data base from your project, and simulate and build.
3. Again drag database.
4. Run your project and check database.